# WPF Relative source- Cannot find source for binding with reference

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, relativesource

have you ever have a problem like this:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext; DataItem=null; target element is 'ContextMenu' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

Code:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

Context Menu is in the:

```
ListBox-> ListBoxItemTemplate -> DataGrid -> DataGrid.ContextMenu
```

I have also another Binding in ListBox control, that works with no problems at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution:

1) Set Tag property on ContextMenu owner to DataContext you wanted. 
2) Set DataContext of ContextMenu to

```
DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

3) Bind your elements like this:

```
Name_Of_Property="{Binding Tag.Name_Of_Property}"
```

Answer (score 4):

context menu is not part of the visual tree, so you use PlacementTarget within your binding

```
 <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource=Self}" />
```

this would use the DataContext of the DataGrid

Comment: And what if i have to change the placement tag, because I have to know which item on the ListBox I have clicked?

Comment: It is really weird, because in another part of my code the solution with Ancestor on ContextMenu worked, but here do not.

Solution with PlacementTarger works, but it's not solution for my problem, because I need DataContext from ListBox or higher.

Comment: you can also use StaticResourcce as Source for your binding, then you not need RelativeSource at all

Comment: or you use the Tag property of your PlacementTarget to bind it to the Datacontext you need and change your path to PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext

Comment: Ok, there is a solution to bind to Ancestor from ContextMenu, but I haven't got enough points to answer my own question on stackoverflow :D
1) Set Tag property on ContextMenu owner to DataContext you wanted.
2) Set DataContext of ContextMenu to DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
3) Bind your elements like this: Name_Of_Property="{Binding Tag.Name_Of_Property}"

Comment: feel free to edit my answer. or just edit your question and add your answer there